# Working with list and split method in list in python

Tags: python, list, split

I have to open a file read it line by line. For each line, I have to split the line into a list of words using the `split()` method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already on the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst=list()
for line in fh:
for each in line:
word = line.split()
if word not in lst:
lst.append(word)
print(lst)
```

after this, I am getting 4 different lists but I am required to get a single list and I am not able to get that

Comment: You need to iterate over every `subword in word`.

Comment: Use `with open(fname) as fh:` or close the file manually.

Comment: What is `for each in line` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Also, `line.split()` returns a _list_ of `word`s, not just one `word`.

Comment: Don't you need to do `for word in line:` instead?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: The indentation as shown in this question cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: Ya thanks since i am learning python from scratch so made some mistake :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst=list()
for line in fh:
    for each in line:
        word = line.split()
        for wrd in word:
            if wrd not in lst:
                lst.append(wrd)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

one line, create a `set` in a set comprehension using `split` on each line, and sort the `set` into a list, using `,key=str.casefold` to sort case-insensitive/locale wise.

```
with open(fname) as f:
  result = sorted({word for line in f for word in line.split()},key=str.casefold)
```

this is particularly efficient since you don't have to use `in` in your existing list, which performs a linear search, very slow if the list is big.

If the file contains punctuation, that won't work very well because `split` won't remove it. Use a regex in that case:

```
result = sorted({word for line in f for word in re.split("\W+",line) if word},key = str.casefold)
```

(you have to add an extra non-empty filter)

Comment: I like the answer but, this doesn't return the result in alphabetical order. I believe `key=str.lower` needs to be added to the sort function.

Comment: not a big deal. Added `,key=str.casefold` which is better since it takes locale/special case folding into account.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in the code

First, it's unclear what you want to do with `for each in line`. I simply removed it.

Second, with `word = line.split()`, you get `word` as **a list of words**. You need to iterate through the list of words and perform actions on individual words.

Then, use `sorted()` to sort the words.

The refined code looks like this:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst=list()
for line in fh:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words
        if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)
fh.close()
print(sorted(lst))
```

Side note: You're not closing the file. Use `fh.close()` (as I added above) or use `with open(fname) as fh:` which will close the file for you after leaving the `with` block.

Comment: Thanks it worked and i was using two nested for loops thats why i think i cannot get a single list and getting first alphabet of each word

Answer (score 0):

Same style as the answers before but rather than using a for loop to get all of the lines I use the `readlines()` functions

The line `lines=fh.readlines()` will return a full list of the lines.

Then you must look at each line with `for line in lines` to see each line.  Then you look at each word in the line with `for word in words`.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst=list()
lines=fh.readlines()
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
with open(fname) as fh:
     unique_words = set(f.read().split())
```

To move that set into list use:

```
unique_words = list(unique_words)
```

and to sort that list:

```
unique_words.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt this idea to your problem.

*words.txt*

```
In linguistics, a word is the smallest element
that can be uttered in isolation with objective
or practical meaning. This contrasts deeply with
a morpheme, which is the smallest unit of meaning
but will not necessarily stand on its own.
```

---

```
import re

with open('words.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    words = f.read()

all_words = re.findall(r'\w+', words)
result = sorted(set(all_words), key=str.lower)
print(result)
```

---

```
['a', 'be', 'but', 'can', 'contrasts', 'deeply', 'element', 'in', 'In', 
'is', 'isolation', 'its', 'linguistics', 'meaning', 'morpheme', 
'necessarily', 'not', 'objective', 'of', 'on', 'or', 'own', 'practical', 
'smallest', 'stand', 'that', 'the', 'This', 'unit', 'uttered', 'which', 
'will', 'with', 'word']
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a interview question by chanse? I am asking because of this part:

> For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list

If this is a interview question, it could very well be that your interviewer does not necessarily want you to use language features to solve this but rather implement a searching algorithm or structure, for example a [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

Assuming this is not the case however, let's go over your code. First, I would recommend you switch from opening the file like you do, `fh = open(fname)` and switch to a `context`, using `with`. Or, at least, close the file handler.

```
word_dictionary = dict()
with open(file_name) as source:
    for line in source:
        for word in line.split():
            if word_dictionary.get(word) is None:
                word_dictionary[word] = True

word_list = [word for word, _ in word_dictionary.items()]
sorted(word_list)

print word_list
```

Let's go over the code together.

First, we define a `dictionary`, called `word_dictionary`. A dictionary or `hash table` is a data structure that allows you to make lookup operation in constant, `O(1)`, time. That is to say, very fast.

Second, we open the file containing the text. This is `with open(file_name) as source:` We call this a `context`. It is a convenient way of dealing with files ( and not only ) that automatically takes care of resource management. I won't go into detail, but i will recommend this [article](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/).

We begin by reading each line, and for each line, we read each word.

```
for line in source:
    for word in line.split():
```

For each word, we check to see if we have already encountered it. We do this by using the `.get()` method of dictionaries. This method will check to see if the argument exists as a key in the dictionary. If it is, it will return the value associated with the key. Otherwise, it will return `None`.

```
if word_dictionary.get(word) is None:
    word_dictionary[word] = True
```

This says that if we encounter a word that we have not seen already, then we register seeing it. Note that it's not necessary to use `True` as a value. Anything different to `None` will work.

One we have seen every word in the text, we do this.

```
word_list = [word for word, _ in word_dictionary.items()]
```

Using `.items()` we iterate over the `key`, `value` pairs of the dictionary. That is to say, if we had a dictionary `d = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}`, calling `for key, value in d.items()` will yield `key = 0, value = "a"` at first, `key = 1, value = "b"` second and finally `key = 2, value = "c"`

In our case, we are not interested in the value. That is why we use `_`. We are only interested in the word.

What the list comprehension will leave us with is a list of all the words you encountered, in a random order. This is because dictionaries make no guarantee on the order to the key, value pairs.

Therefore, we need to sort.

```
sorted(word_list)
```

Since the `word_list` variable is going to be a list of string and since strings are comparable by default, they will be sorted.

---

Now, there are several things to consider. First, `.split()` will consider `'this'` and `'this!'` to be different words. You may or may not want this.

If you do not want this, you can use the 'string' module to check against punctuation or you can use a regex to clean up your word.

The second thing to consider is capitalisation. You make no mention of this. Are you allowed to lower or capitalise your text? If you are, your life will be easier. You lowercase everything and your problems go away.

If you are not allowed to lower your text, you will have to change the sort call. this is because capital letters are "smaller" then lowercase ones.

```
>>> "A" < "a"
True
```

This will manifest in the following way.

```
>>> sorted(["b", "a", "C"])
['C', 'a', 'b']
```

Most likely you expect `["a", "b", "C"]` here. In this case, I recommend you look into the `cpm` argument for sort.

Comment: No, it was not an interview question but just a part of learning python while working on assignments